# Exporting XLS file from PHP and replacing the old ones

Tags: php, export-to-excel

With this code, I can export (or download) XLS file named data.xls automatically :

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.xls");
```

But if another file named 'data.xls' already exists in the Downloads folder, the exported XLS file's name become 'data(1).xls'.

I want the exported one replaces the old one.

Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cant. From your web page you cant control the browser "save" dialogs or how the OS will handle duplicates. You can only pass the file name you wanted, then the browser and the OS will manage everything (like duplicate names)